# How to connect to Snowflake database through R if MFA (multi factor authentication) is required through Duo app?

Tags: r, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbconnection, rjdbc

I am working on a project which requires me to connect through R to a Snowflake database to pull data from it. However, since we use multifactor authentication to access the DB. I couldnt establish a connection and end up getting timed out.

I use the following piece to code to try to connect,

```
library("RJDBC")

#Establish connection to snowflake

jdbcDriver <- JDBC(driverClass="com.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver", classPath="snowflake-jdbc-3.0.19.jar") 

jdbcConnection<-dbConnect(jdbcDriver, "jdbc:snowflake://<<company>>.<<region>>.snowflakecomputing.com", "username","password")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check for parameter 'networkTimeout' value? It should be either 0 (default) or a higher value to wait for the response from the server.

For Duo push mechanism this should be straightforward and no changes to the connection string need to be made but for DUO passcode there have to be made additions.

Comment: Still end up facing the same timeout issue, to be more precise with my question we use duo push authentication.

Comment: You can use "net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver" instead. As "com.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver" has been deprecated.